# Create a c++ file for using multiple database

Tags: c++, mysql, postgresql

I have the c++ project working on MySQL database.
recently i am moving to the PostgreSQL database so i am facing the difficulties like the queries in sql written is like

> select UserName form UserInfo;

will not work in pgSQL it would be like

> select "UserName" from "UserInfo";

so i want to make a file that could tackle this two difference syntax could anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you need to support both? Can you just pick one or the other and stick with it?

Comment: It depends on situations suppose now MySQL licencing tells that if you are using MySQL than you have to make your source code open.
in pgSQL there is no such limitations .
so now i have to shift for the pgSQL .
**now think if situation changes and third database may come in market  than what happens??**

Comment: @DineshDabhi "if you are using MySQL than you have to make your source code open." Not true: http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html Also, you can use the GPL version if all you're doing is *connecting* to MySQL. If you want to embed MySQL then you might want to look at the other license.

Answer (score 0):

You should standardize on ANSI SQL, in this case "UserName" which MySQL will understand too under appropriate SQL modes.  Then you should look at the minimum you need to do to support this (in this case, if it is MySQL, set the appropriate `sql_mode`).